# AttributeError: 'datetime.date' object has no attribute 'column_num'

Tags: python

I am trying to extract sql output in excel with below code. But i am getting error

> AttributeError: 'datetime.date' object has no attribute 'column_num'

code:

```
  for p in (row):
        column_num = 1
        _= ws0.cell(row = row_number,column= column_num,value = (p.column_num))
```

Comment: Perhaps `row` is not what you expect. Did you try printing it?

Comment: @Paul Rooney Thanks for reply. Yes below is 4 columns                                  .[2017-09-01, 35053479.1102, 230891, 5372148.7940]

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to access a property called `column_num` on `row`, where `row` is a `datetime` object. Python's `datetime` class has no property called `column_num`.

Comment: It seems you are not looping over what you think you are looping over. From the scant information shown here, it's impossible to guess your intentions. It's true a datetime has no member column_num. It also is not subscriptable (so p[1] wouldn't work). I suggest you expand your question to make it clear what you are trying to achieve. Otherwise the question isn't clear.

Comment: @Paul Rooney Thanks for reply. My "row" has four columns from sql query. First couplmn is a date. I want o populated these 4 columns in excel file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're working with something like pandas and trying to access an item using a key. So try `p[column_num]`.

Comment: Hi @Ken Wei  i tried p[column_num] but it gave me error                                      TypeError: 'datetime.date' object is not subscriptable